# Disparity between populated id column and returned value from hibernate after save

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence, database-trigger

A sequence is used to generate id for a customer table and then using trigger to populate the id column as a varchar value.
The trigger is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER_ID_TRIGGER
before insert on CUSTOMER  
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
for each row
begin 
 -- :new.user_id := 'CUST' || :new.user_id  ;
select 'CUST' || SEQ_CUSTOMER_ID.nextval into :new.user_id from dual;
end USER_ID_TRIGGER;
```

So, each insert in the column is like 'CUST1', 'CUST3', etc.

The trigger can't be changed.
I am using hibernate save(customer) method to save customer objects in the db. Problem is the return id value I am getting is (as expected) different from the one that is ultimately saved in the table.
For example, if the id populated in the column is 'CUST19', the hibernate code returns 18.
My question is, if the code returns a value of 210, will it be safe for me to assume that the populated value is CUST211?

Comment: How are you inserting new rows?

Comment: dao.getSession().save(customer)

Comment: I mean is there any insert statement like insert into table (col1,col2,...) values (x,x...)

Comment: I am using Hibernate to save the details in the table. just using Session class's save(Object var1) method. Before calling the save method, I am setting all properties for the customer object except for the id which is generated by the sequence and then populated after the trigger.